# Can Intel SRT on one SATA channel accelerate a separate SSD on another channel?

Tags: ssd, raid, intel-rst, msata, smart-response

My laptop can house both a 2.5" drive and an mSATA card. I have a SSD in the 2.5" slot already with enough capacity for my needs, if I added a 64GB mSATA card would I get faster system performance by using Intel SRT?

I have the mSATA card already, but it's not installed yet. I can't simply try install it to experiment besause I'll need to switch from AHCI to RAID (which Windows will not like).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes; Relative to your current configuration it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, do you know where I could find benchmarks for this? I had trouble searching for this because I couldn't figure out a good search syntax.